# Convert decimal into Feet.Inches

Tags: c#, converters

I need to be able to convert from a standard double into another double (or float) that is rationalized into feet.inches. The tool that reads this output reads the first number before the . as "feet" and anything after as "inches".

The tool reads 1.12 as 2 feet, because it's 1 foot and 12 inches, this is why we are rounding to one decimal place unless it is exactly x feet and 11 inches.

The goal of this function is to pass in a standard decimal and return its conversion into feet and inches, via this specific format.

```
public static string ToDecimalFeetString(double num)
{
    return *new ratio, **as a string**, rounded to one decimal place, unless 11 or 10 inches*
}

ToDecimalFeet(0.4) // returns 0.5 (0.4 feet == 5 inches)
ToDecimalFeet(50.9) // returns 50.11 (50.9 feet == 50 feet and 11 inches)
ToDecimalFeet(10.8) // returns 10.10 (10.8 feet == 10 feet and 10 inches)
ToDecimalFeet(29.1) // returns 29.1 (29.1 feet == 29 feet and ~1 inch, when rounded)
ToDecimalFeet(1.00) // returns 1.00 (1.00 feet == 1 foot and zero inches)
```

**Edit:** This apparently needs a clarification edit, so here goes:

Some comments mentioned "Why use imperial?" - Good question, though this conversion is for a completely separate (production) tool that uses feet.inches - so that's what we have to go with.

"What if you need to return x feet and 10 inches?" This is a great question, for this case we would return x.10 -- Yes, the value of this is also the exact same as x.1 which we would return for one inch, but the separate tool reads them differently, *which brings me to a silly mistake I made.*

We are actually returning a string, not a double. So it is totally okay to print "0.10" and "0.1" as they are completely different values to this other tool, my apologies for the confusion. I have reflected this in my above method.

Edit 2: Fixed formatting error

Comment: Sounds like a great case to use metric and not bother with imperial. however that aside, what have you tried? you have no problem yet, just a desire

Comment: What is the question? What part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: It really seems like you're trying to make a double/float represent something that is not a double/float. It's very much confusing that return values of 0.1, 0.11, and 0.2 represent 1, 11, and 2 inches respectively. Unless I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: You are probably better off to make a class struct for this and back it with metric, and us it where ever you need the conversion help or return it, over load the operators as needed

Comment: Piggybacking on @CodeStranger's concern, I see a pretty huge problem if you need to return 10 inches.

Comment: Well I understand what he wants. StageCodes has provided few samples to clarify the logic required - so if the question can be Opened. I can post the answer

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Please don't edit answers directly into the question.

Comment: @Amy - Dont have any other way of writing the answer. Question is closed    public static double ToDecimalFeet(double num)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(num))
        return 0;

    // Strip decimal part
    long feetsFull = (long)num;
    // Get decimal part
    double feetsDecimal = num - feetsFull;

    feetsDecimal = Math.Round(12 * feetsDecimal, 0);

    return double.Parse($"{feetsFull}.{feetsDecimal}");
}

Comment: I just made a clarification edit. Hopefully we can see it re-opened soon. I had made a mistake anyway in my OP which the edit covers. Thanks for wanting to help!

Comment: @AustinTFrench I'm basically stuck getting started, yes. I have had solutions that only work until the 9th decimal (so 0.9), but my problem lies in converting from, say 50.9 to 50.11 (50.9 decimal to 50 feet and 11 inches => Feet.Inches)

Comment: I feel it's answerable now, although please add the code that you have if you have it.

Comment: Doubles cannot accurately represent fractions in tenths other than exact fractions of powers of two, like 0.5 and 0.25.  This is a very, very, very bad idea that you are pursuing and you should stop immediately. If you need a "pair of integers" type then make such a type. If you wish to represent a length in feet as a double then 1.5 should be one foot, six inches; write a converter that rounds fractions to the nearest 12th.

Comment: IMHO, return a struct with two fields and a custom `ToString()`.

Comment: Lest you think I am exaggerating: Visual Basic used to represent dates as a double where the signed integer part was the number of days since 30 December 1899, and the unsigned fractional part was the fraction of that day gone by. So 0.25 was 6 AM 30 December 1899. And so was -0.25! Now try writing code that answers the question "how many minutes apart are those two timestamps?"  The bugs were *horrible*. Just don't do it. **A double is not a data structure; it is a single value that represents a real-valued physical quantity**, not a pair of values.

Comment: It seems the number of comments is directly proportional to the unclarity of the question OR the oddity of the requirements. But, at the very least it would make sense to represent the result in the expected notation: 5' 10" for 5 feet 10 inch. Call me crazy if you must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do it would be to take the input number, get the "whole" part (which won't change) and then get the "decimal" part separately and multiply it by 12. We can then return these combined as a string:

```
public static string ToDecimalFeet(double num)
{
    var wholePart = Math.Truncate(num);
    var decimalPart = num - wholePart;
    var inches = Math.Round(12 * decimalPart);
    return $"{wholePart}.{inches}";
}
```

or simply:

```
public static string ToDecimalFeet(double num)
{
    return $"{Math.Truncate(num)}.{Math.Round(12 * (num - Math.Truncate(num)))}";
}
```

Comment: It's better style to use `Truncate` or `Floor` -- depending on what behaviour you want for negative numbers -- than to cast a double to int. That way it will still continue to work even if the double overflows the int.

Comment: Thanks @EricLippert. Updated sample.